# Fetching data from URL with different id in React Hooks

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

I am new to React.

The for loop is used to fetch data from the url with different ids.

The object from data contains same keys and different values.

What I want to do is I want to store these data objects into array with index.

Looking like the following:

```
dataArr [
 0: {key: 1, value: 1},
 1: {key: 2, value: 2},
 2: {key: 3, value: 3}
]
```

Here is what I have tried.

```
var ids = [1,2,3]
const [data, setData] = useSate({});
const dataArr = [];
const fetchData = async() => {
  for(var i =0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    axios.get(`http://myURL/${ids[i]}`)
    .then(res => {
       dataArr.push(setData(res.data))
     })
   }
}


useEffect(() => {
   fetchData ();
},[]);
console.log(dataArr[0]) //undefined
console.log(dataArr) // empty
console.log(data) // get objects independently
```

Can anybody advise me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`axios.get` is asynchronous and the `console.log` statements get executed before the promises resolve. I would recommend reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) answer to gain a better understanding.

You can create an array of promises and await them using `await Promise.all(...)` to fetch all the responses and then call `setData` with the new state. You should also set the initial state to an empty array.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const ids = [1, 2, 3]
    const responses = await Promise.all(
      ids.map((id) => axios.get(`http://myURL/${id}`))
    )
    setData(responses.map((res) => res.data))
  }

  fetchData()
}, [])
```

If you set up [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin-react-hooks), it would display a warning to add `setData` to the dependency array since the effect depends on it. It's totally fine to add it since the function's reference won't change on re-renders.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const ids = [1, 2, 3]
    const responses = await Promise.all(
      ids.map((id) => axios.get(`http://myURL/${id}`))
    )
    setData(responses.map((res) => res.data))
  }

  fetchData()
}, [setData])
```

Comment: @ewef You're welcome. Did you understand why the code in the question didn't work?

Comment: As far as I understand from the answer in the link you sent, my code is executed immediately. Thus, I should have used ```Promise``` to contain the immediate objects. In my code, instead of using ```Promise```, I pushed objects to array. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @ewef "my code is executed immediately." Exactly. "Thus, I should have used Promise to contain the immediate objects." Not sure if I understand this part. The response is only available when the promise resolves and you cannot access it outside the async function. Does that make sense?

Comment: I really appreciate your thoughtful explanation. I have never thought of ```Promise```.